# CGBitmapContextGetData() returning NULL

Tags: ios

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

self._bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(
        NULL,
        pixelWidth,
        pixelHeight,
        8,
        4 * pixelWidth,
        colorSpace,
        (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst );
if (self._bitmapContext) {
    // this is NULL
    char *bitmapData = CGBitmapContextGetData(self._bitmapContext);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Couldn't create bitmap\n");
}
```

> If you passed NULL for the data
>   pointer when creating your bitmap context, it is safe to get the data
>   pointer in iOS 4.0 and later and OS X v10.6 and later only. In earlier
>   versions of the operating system, passing NULL for the data parameter
>   is not supported and may lead to crashes when attempting to access
>   this data using this function

I'm targeting iOS 8.1

Quartz doesn't seem to be creating the backing data - and thus I can't create images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess that the last parameter is not sufficient for iOS to create the bitmap - I just looked in some of my code and this is what I was using in my iOS app:

```
kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little
```

If that doesn't do it please log the pixel width/height you are using (please actually log it, not presume).

Comment: Sorry it took some time to respond. This is a little embarrassing - I don't now how I didn't add a flag for byte ordering. Thank you!

Comment: I cannot even count the number of embarrassing coding errors I've made in my career and I asked for help here several times as well. Be glad you didn't waste more time on it!